# Database modelling string as enumeration or action as boolean values?

Tags: database, database-design, architecture, data-modeling

what is the best approach to model certain user actions in a database? let say you could an extendable set of actions like: **login, logout, profile update and deactivation** and so on....

first approach storing the actions as string in one column....

```
CREATE TABLE user_actions
(
  id bigserial NOT NULL,
  user_id integer,
  created_on timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
  action character varying(20) NOT NULL,
)
```

or creating a boolean column for each action, more more when adding new actions but maybe faster and easier searched...

```
CREATE TABLE user_actions
(
  id bigserial NOT NULL,
  user_id integer,
  created_on timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
  login boolean NOT NULL,
  logout boolean NOT NULL,
  profile_update boolean NOT NULL,
  profile_deactivated boolean NOT NULL,
)
```

would like to get your feedback and suggestions

Answer (score 1):

I would split the two.  Create another table call it "AVAILABLE_ACTIONS" with an integer key that you can use as a foreign key to your USER_ACTIONS table.  This gives you better performance, while not having to issue DDL every time a new action comes around.